# How to adapt an algorithm for grey images for colour images?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have been using https://gist.github.com/chsasank/4d8f68caf01f041a6453e67fb30f8f5a for image processing. This expects an image with only one channel (see `assert len(image.shape) == 2`) how can the code be adapted such that it works for colour images - so images with three channels?

Comment: What was bad about the question?

Comment: It probably depends on the chosen algorithm. You could apply the algorithm on each color channel separately then somehow merge, you could grayscale the image before, you could convert the colors to a different colorspace before or something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to split the image into channels and then after remapping, merge back together.

```
# make sure it's not gray
assert len(image.shape) == 3

# grab the image resolution
shape = image.shape[:2]

# random_state, gaussian and meshgrid
.
.
.

#calculate indices just as before
indices = np.reshape(x+dx, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(y+dy, (-1, 1))

# split the image into 3 channels
b, g, r = cv2.split(image)

# do the mapping on all of the channels separately
b = map_coordinates(b, indices, order=1).reshape(shape)
g = map_coordinates(g, indices, order=1).reshape(shape)
r = map_coordinates(r, indices, order=1).reshape(shape)

# return merged result
return cv2.merge((b,g,r))
```